# WinAPI for Game Controllers

Tags: c++, winapi

I know that all windows platforms automatically detect when a game controller is connected. I also know there is a WinAPI for polling these controllers. I can't seem to find the functions I am looking for anywhere.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Brendan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use either [DirectInput or XInput from the DirectX SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee417014%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Or use the [XNA](http://www.xna.com/) toolkit available from Microsoft, this includes the DirectX runtime and makes it easy to develop a game and would be certain that there is an API by XNA to interact with game controllers.

Hope this helps,
Best regards,
Tom.

Comment: Yeah, but isn't the XNA framework only in C#? I'm working on a private project for school, and I'm set on using c++.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep it simple, you can use the [joystick APIs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd757116%28VS.85%29.aspx).